# USB HDD not working on linux

Tags: linux, external-hdd

I have a WD My Passport 1 TB external hard drive which is giving me some problems on different linux machines:

- When I plug it in, nothing happens
- Gparted when detecting connected devices says *"Error opening /dev/sdb: No such device or address"* and it doesn't list the hard drive
- Typing on terminal `sudo fdisk -l` the hard drive is not listed

This happens on both my main Debian PC and on my Raspberry Pi, but I can use the hard drive perfectly normally on my Mac.

I can't check its S.M.A.R.T. status since it's a USB hard drive, but I don't think the HDD is failing, because if so it wouldn't work on my Mac. I checked and reformatted the drive several times on my Mac but it still doesn't work on linux.

Any ideas on what's going on?

**Edit:** here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 000: ID 1058:0730 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
```

As you can see, the device is listed here (Bus 001 Device 000).

**Edit x2:** This is kern.log file since when the hard drive was connected:

- via dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e11tb8bsstxrgyl/kern.log
- via fpaste: http://fpaste.org/127795/87285661/.

**Edit x3:** The hard drive has 4 partitions; two are HFS+ and two are FAT32. The partition table is GUID.

**Edit x4:** I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110) about one error in the kernel log file I found too, which means the USB 3.0 drive is requesting too much power from the computer. However I tried using a USB power splitter cable (so that the HDD could have 1000 mA instead of 500 mA) and it didn't solve the problem. The HDD seems to be rated 600 mA, but I've always used on USB 2.0 ports without problems.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`? (edit your question with this output)

Comment: When you plug it in, what are the lines added to `/var/log/kern.log` (or to `dmesg`)?

Comment: Do you get the same messages in your Debian PC's kernel log as you do on the RPi?

Comment: Also, does this drive have a password enabled on it with the WD utility?

Comment: @derobert yes, I get the same messages. And no, the drive is not password protected.

Comment: With little messaging to go on it's likely an issue b/w your system's BIOS + the USB HDD. The device isn't showing up to the kernel in any meaningful way. it's not really the kernel's issue. I have many devices around the house that just don't work under Linux but work perfectly fine with Windows + OSX.

Comment: @slm I understand what you mean, but I'm afraid it can't be like that. I've always used that hard drive with both the Debian PC and the Raspberry Pi without any problem, so why would it give problems _now_ if it's a BIOS issue?

Comment: @user2747949 - if that's the case then it's either a recent update to the OS'es or something about the HDD. To split the tie, does the HDD work in anything other than the OSX box? Also I assume you've swapped out the cable and power cycled the Linux boxes in your tests?

Comment: @slm The HDD works on Windows too; I have power cycled the machines many times but I didn't swap out the cable because I don't have another compatible one. However since it works on other OSs I don't think the cable could be the cause. As a last resort, I may contact Western Digital and ask for a replacement, but the HDD is out of warranty by now so I'll probably have to buy a new one. The problem is that I don't even know if it's just a problem about it.

Comment: If it's working on 2 computers, then I'd agree it's likely not the cable or the HDD, but the OS. Just crossing possibilities off the list. As to why I would probably get a liveCD and boot one of the systems with that to confirm. I would expect Knoppix or an Ubuntu LiveCD would be able to see it.

Comment: @slm unfortunately, the same problem occurs on the latest Ubuntu LiveCD too. Also, the kernel logs are the same.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo lsmod | grep hfs`  I have a hunch that the newer Debian based kernels are compiled w/o hfs filesystem support

Comment: @ECarterYoung The output is `squashfs 26695 1`

Comment: My hunch was correct.  You need to go into your kernel config and under Filesystem Support enable HFS and HFS+.

Answer (score 2):

If your harddrive is formatted as HFS+ (which it would be, if it is formatted as a native Mac drive) then you should make sure that hfs drivers are installed on your Linux machines.

On Debian, as root:

```
apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs
```

That should enable read access to the drive, but write access will be disabled until you turn OFF journaling (which should be done from within OS X's Disk Utility application).

Answer (score 0):

try doing both:

```
fdisk -l 
mkdir /mnt/sdb1 
edit /etc/fstab file and add line similar to this:
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/sdb1           vfat    defaults        0       0 
mount -a
```

if that fails try this:

```
sudo fdisk -l  
Then mount with 
sudo mount -t ntfs(depends) /dev/sdb1 /media
```

This has got to work, if its Linux and it has a USB port, you have to be able to mount the drive unless there's a hardware issue on both ends. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misread your `kern.log` but in this file, your drive seems to be referenced as `/dev/sda` not `/dev/sdb`. Did you try to use `usbcore.old_scheme_first=1` as a grub boot parameter?

Anyway, according to [Device descriptor read/64, error-110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110) it's a power related trouble and there seems to be some kind of workaround [here](http://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error). The good old "try to turn it off and on again" seems to do the trick (unplugging all your usb stuff before turning on again)